# Spring throws NoClassDefFoundError when instantiating a bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring bean.

```
@Component
public class Omg {

    public void omg() throws IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = null;
        InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
        is.read();
    }

}
```

I am not using it in a servlet container. **This is just for the sake of example.**

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

This line throws exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletInputStream.`
Servlet api is **not** in classpath in runtime. Okay, I understand that `NoClassDefFoundError` should be thrown when omg method runs. The question is: why is it thrown when spring tries to instantiate the bean and why `ServletInputStream` rather than `HttpServlerRequest`?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletInputStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:234)
```

UPDATE:
However this works fine

```
public class A {}

public class B {

    public void method() {
        A a = new A();
    } 

}

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }

}
```

compile all three classes. remove A.class. run main method of C class. It works fine.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a different instance of a new server? also, which server are you using? I recently had a similar issue and the issue was that the server in eclipse (not tomcat itsself) was messed up. Running the project on a different server in eclipse seemed to work.

Comment: @sparks I am not using no web server. This is just for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

> public class NoClassDefFoundError extends LinkageError
>
> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   **as part of creating a new instance using the new expression**) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

```
public class A {}

public class B {
  public void m(A a) {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     B b = new B();
  }
}

javac A.java // OK

javac B.java // OK

// remove A.class

java B

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @user1745356 I added an example

Comment: Okay, your example throws exception. Still unclear why. I updated my question.